# FB Live mode not showing approved API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-permissions

**Q1**. In Development mode, Requested FB Graph API for approval and it was approved by FB.
While switching Development to Live mode, My Permission and features not showing approved API in a list .
Is some setting missing from my end ?

**Q2**. Continue with Q1 , In Live when trying to connect FB  showing below errors.

```
Invalid Scopes: user_friends, read_insights, user_posts, manage_pages. This message is only
shown to developers. Users of your app will ignore these permissions if present. 
Please read the documentation for valid permissions at: 
[https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions][1]
```

user_friends, read_insights, user_posts, manage_pages this is already approved API

How should solve above issues.
Thank you for help.